# Exception safety in array assignment using postincremented index

Tags: c++, arrays, exception, increment

In this code:

```
template<class T>
void Stack<T>::Push( const T& t )
{
  if( vused_ == vsize_ )                           // grow if necessary
  {
    size_t vsize_new = vsize_*2+1;                 // by some grow factor
    T* v_new = NewCopy( v_, vsize_, vsize_new );
    delete[] v_;                                   // this can't throw
    v_ = v_new;                                    // take ownership
    vsize_ = vsize_new;
  }
  v_[vused_] = t;
  vused++;
}
```

we try to be exception safe and exception neutral. It is achieved by a means of having `NewCopy()` helper function (that copies pointed memory and returns a pointer to a copied values) which follows these principles (we are not interested in that function here, it is exception safe & neutral). Lastly, all works because

```
  v_[vused_] = t;
  vused++;
```

we only change state of Stack if assignment does not throw. If we wrote

```
  v_[vused_++] = t;
```

would the exception safety be violated? My guess is yes (postincrement operator returns old value but it **does** increment variable **before** return, and then after it returned the assignment is performed, so in case of exception the object state is invalid). But I might be mistaken (?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

C++ Standard n3337 **§** 8.3.4/6 Arrays

> Note: Except where it has been declared for a class (13.5.5), the
>   subscript operator [] is interpreted in such a way that E1[E2] is
>   identical to *((E1)+(E2)). Because of the conversion rules that apply
>   to +, if E1 is an array and E2 an integer, then E1[E2] refers to the
>   E2-th member of E1. Therefore, despite its asymmetric appearance,
>   subscripting is a commutative operation.

Thus

```
v_[vused_++] = t;
```

is not different from

```
*((v_)+(vused_++)) = t;
```

so it is clear that `++` will evaluate before assignment and in case of exception being thrown by `T::operator=` state of the object is invalid.

Answer (score 3):

From the standard, 1.9/15:

> When calling a function (whether or not the function is inline), every value computation and side effect associated with any argument expression, or with the postfix expression designating the called function, is sequenced before execution of every expression or statement in the body of the called function.

So when we call:

```
v_[vused_++]
```

which is to say:

```
*(v_ + vused_++)
```

The postincrement operator is sequenced *before* the dereference. Thus, regardless of what happens in that call, even if it throws, `vused_` will be incremented. So this will violate the strong exception guarantee if the subsequent assignment throws since `vused_` will be incremented. This is easy to convince yourself:

```
void foo(int ) { throw std::runtime_error(""); }

int main() {
    int ctr = 0;
    try {
        foo(ctr++);
    }
    except(...) { }

    std::cout << ctr << std::endl; // prints 1
}
```

But if we had called `foo(ctr); ctr++`, it'd print 0.

Comment: Except that since `v_` is a pointer, there's no call to `v_.operator[]`.

Comment: @JoachimPileborg Haha, crap, I got confused by `Stack`. Lemme find the right quote then and edit it, one min...

Comment: @JoachimPileborg Hm, I'm not sure how to correctly word it for just a pointer. It's the right idea at least.

Answer (score 0):

Given that NewCopy supports the strong guarantee then the code as you have it is exception-safe.

Agree with @Barry that making the change you propose will make it exception-unsafe (and provide no more performance).

Again,

Why on earth are you writing your own stack then the standard library contains a fully optimised, exception-safe implementation?

Comment: @Richard Hodges NewCopy is exception safe and neutral as the rest of code, I am just referring to last two lines